# Змейка на C#. Помогите придумать алгоритм бота.

Tags: c#, алгоритм, разработка-игр, бот

Змейка отлажена.
Пишу бота для своей игры змейка.
Для поиска пути использую волновой алгоритм.
Волновой алгоритм успешно справляется с поиском пути.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Проблемы:**
Когда змейка наберет достаточный размер и съест еду, после которого змейка оказывается в тупике. Волновой алгоритм уже не подходит, так как нет пути до еды.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для решения нужно:

1. Предупредить попадание в тупик.
2. Если уже попал, то найти выход из тупика.

Подскажите алгоритм предупреждения попадания в тупик.

Пока придуман плановый алгоритм для поиска пути.

```
private Путь ПоискПути()
{

    Путь кратчайшийПуть = ПоискКратчайшегоПути();
    if (кратчайшийПуть != null)
    {
        bool результат = false;
        результат = ПрогнозТупика(кратчайшийПуть);
        if (!результат)
            return кратчайшийПуть;
        else
        {
            Путь путь = НайтиОбходнойПуть();
            if (путь != null)
            {
                return путь;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
    // в тупике
    else
    {
        Путь путь = НайтиВыходИзТупика();
        if (путь != null)
        {
           return путь;
        }
        else
        {
           return null; 
        }
    }

}
```

Кому интересен сам проект, [ссылка на GitHub](https://github.com/Cuprumbur/Snake)

Comment: а не достаточно ли будет просто пересчитывать преграды,включая туда саму змейку?

Comment: ...`if (путь != null)
            {
                return путь;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }`, что правда?

Comment: @EV_Hyper, это написано, чтобы вместо null  в будущем добавить дополнительный метод поиска. По хорошему туда вызовы исключения добавить надо

Comment: @РагнарТолстов, тело змейки при просчете пути является преградой.
Периодически возникает ситуация, когда следующий шаг, после поедания, ведет в тупик, из которого уже нет выхода

Comment: Как успехи?....

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин, пока не приступал. Как сделаю, я вам уведомление отправлю

Answer (score 4):

Что такое тупик? Тупик это часть пространства с наименьшей площадью.

Каждый раз когда у вас есть выбор куда повернуть, и при разном выборе вы попадаете в разные фигуры с разной площадью, вы выбираете повернуть туда где площадь больше.

По возможности ещё смотреть будет ли разбиение пространства при определённом ходе, и по возможности избегать разбиений.

**Обновлено:**
Выход из тупика. ищем в тупике точку самого раннего (перкого) вхождения змейки в обрамление тупика, то есть самую заднюю часть, и стараемся идти к этой точке, архивируя путь, то есть используя пространство тупика по максимому.

Comment: тупик - часть пространства игры, из которого нет пути.

Comment: @CuprumBur пути куда?

Comment: Пути до еды. Каждый ход змейки - это шаг к еде. Без пути до еды, нет пути

Comment: @CuprumBur Тогда выбирайте ту сторону где больше еды и где больше свободного места.

Comment: Попробую, у Вас будут еще рекомендации для улучшения алгоритма?

Comment: @CuprumBur  Да. при движении надо стараться сделать так что бы было как можно дальше от разбиений на части, желательно что бы части были соединены не просто одной клеткой, а проходом пошире. Как это реализовать с ходу не скажу, но в любом случае хороший алгоритм движения змейки это достаточно сложная вещь.

Comment: @CuprumBur Кстати тупиком по сути является только та меньшая часть которая по размеру меньше самой змейки... это тоже надо учитывать. То что я предложил это не готовый алгоритм, но идеи которые можно воплотить в алгоритме.

Comment: @CuprumBur сразу бы не торопился реализоввывать, продумать желательно, сначала. сейчас ещё допишу ответ.

Comment: @CuprumBur интересно было бы написать обучающийся алгоритм... но это я бы сказал очень продвинутая задача. Я думаю можно на каждом шаге стараться анализировать коэфициент хорошести (антитупиковости ситуации) в случае всех вариантов хода, на основе ряда оценок, и оценки сумирывать с коэфициентами, а вот сами коэффициенты можно уже сделать что бы шло самообучение.

Comment: Самообучение запланировано на будущее, а сейчас с вашими идеями буду думать как сделать алгоритм, который не убьет змейку и будет есть еду самым эффективным способом

Answer (score 1):

Сделать функцию хорошести `f` позиции в зависимости от выбора.
То есть при каждом варианте выбора эта функция будет расчитываться.

Эта функция будет состоять из набора модулей (подфункций).

1. Количество разбиений пространства при выборе.
2. Объём пространства в которое попадаем.
3. Количество еды.
4. Насколько оставшееся пространство соединённое ( самое узкое место 1 клетка, 2,3,4...).

и другие модули которые вы придумаете позже.

Далее каждый модуль вычисляет своё значение и в общей функции все эти значения складываются с определёнными коэффициентами.

```
f = m1 * k1 + m2 * k2 + ... + mn * kn;
```

`mi` это результат вычислений модуля `i`.
`ki` это коэффициент, которые задаётся вручную.

Позже можно будет сделать самообучение по этим коэффициентам.

Далее для каждого выбора рассчитываем функцию `f` и выбираем выбор с наибольшим значением.

Answer (score 1):

Просто как идея:

1. Определяем все кратчайшие маршруты до еды волновым алгоритмом
2. Для каждого из маршрутов делаем следующее:

   - считаем количество ходов для маршрута (сколько клеток надо проползти)
   - увеличиваем змею спереди на маршрут, уменьшаем сзади на маршрут. Получаем положение змеи, как если бы она подползла к еде
   - проверяем, если мы в тупике - то маршрут не годен, отметаем его. Если не в тупике, то маршрут годен.
3. Если годных маршрутов больше 0, то берем первый
4. Если годных маршрутов ноль, то добавляем псевдо-точку где-то подальше от змеи и считаем маршут до неё. В конце возврат в п.1